# Insert result into multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT:

Im trying to submit a form with a title and body but i want the title to go to one table and body to go to another table, this in itself i can do but i need the ID generated from the title being inserted into its table to then be inserted into a field in the table the body is inserted so as to keep them linked.

What i have so far: **I know its not pretty and its not safe,** i will be reworking them once i learn how to do it properly.

```
if (@$_POST['post'])
{

$body = @$_POST['body'];     
$title = @$_POST['title'];
$BoardID = @$_POST['BoardID'];
$MemberID = @$_POST['MemberID'];

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");     

include ('connect.php');    

$insert =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO threads VALUES ('','$BoardID','$title','$date','$MemberID','','')");


if($insert) {
    header("location: ?p=posts&thread=$Thread_ID");
    exit();
}

}
```

I need to somehow get $Thread_ID which has been generated in the insert and add that to a second insert for adding body to the post table, if that makes sense.

I tried getting the latest $Thread_ID and adding +1 but if multiple threads are posted at once they might get crossed over.

How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: _"How would i go about fixing this?"_ start by not using `@` to suppress warnings/errors that _Are there to help_, like the `E_DEPRECATED` notice when using `mysql_*` functions. _DEPRECATED_ isn't meaningless, you know...

Comment: Although deprecated, you can look at the [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)-function

Comment: why suppressing warning for `$_POST` ? also, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Bobby Tables strikes again! http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You have 2 queries, but you execute the last one only. Logic issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905381/2-table-interaction-insert-get-result-insert?rq=1

Comment: i dont know why i had the @ there i was getting no errors

Comment: _" I know its not pretty and its not safe, i will be reworking them once i learn how to do it properly"_, if you know the code is no good, why not learn how to do it properly, before writing something bad? You're basically saying: _"I know my leg is broken, but I'll use a band-aid until I know where to find a cast"_

Comment: You should not rely on LatestID+1 as it might end up with cross over. Insert thread and use insert_id to put data in post table.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP manual tell us:

> This extension Mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   ([see ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).)

You must use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), to make a connection between PHP and a MySQL database.

**mysqli**

If you want the id of the inserted row, you can use `$mysqli->insert_id` ([ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php))

Example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

**PDO**

If you want the id of the inserted row, you can use `$dbh->lastInsertId();` ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php))

And don't forget to [sanatize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130323/2550094) all your inputs.

Comment: *sidenote:* don't forget to mention: `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: True again Shivan! Thanks, I will add that now!

Answer (score -2):

You need to execute both insert queries separately.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO threads VALUES ('','$BoardID','$title','$date','$MemberID','','')";

$result = @mysql_query($insert);  
$Thread_ID=@mysql_insert_id();

$insert = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES ('','$BoardID',$Thread_ID','$body','$date','$MemberID')";   

$result = @mysql_query($insert);
```

Thanks,

Comment: you shouldn't advise the OP keep using deprecated functions. `insert_id()` is also included in MySQLi

Comment: I just amended his code. since he was not using mysqli functions.